# Showing PDE solution map (takes initial condition and gives solution) is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $$u_t -\Delta u = f$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
where $f \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$ and $u_0 \in L^2(\Omega)$ with $V=H^1(\Omega)$.

Define the map $S:H \to \{ u \in L^2(0,T;V) : u_t \in L^2(0,T;V^*)\}$ by $S(u_0) = u$, i.e. it takes the initial condition and gives the solution.

GHow do I show that this map is continuous?

The map is not linear so boundedness does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u^n_0 \to u_0$ in $H$ where the $u^n_0$ are initial data such that
$$u^n_t - \Delta u^n = f$$
$$u^n(0) = u^n_0$$

i.e. $S(u^n_0) = u^n$. Likewise, let $S(u_0) = u$. We need to show that $S(u^n_0) \to S(u_0)$. Consider the difference of the PDEs $u^n$ and $u$ satisfy:
$$(u^n-u)_t - \Delta (u^n - u) = 0$$
$$(u^n-u)(0) = u^n_0 - u_0$$
From standard theory, this PDE has unique solution that depends continuously on data:
$$|u^n-u| \leq C|u_0^n-u_0|$$
but the RHS tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ by assumption.  So we have shown that $S$ is (Lipschitz and) continuous.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Could you use the assumption "this PDE has unique solution that depends continuously on data" on the heat equation directly?

Comment: @Vintarel Doh, yeah that's stupid of me :D